# How to create time intervals between states in an FSM

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, fsm

I would like to create a timer interval between the execution of a state in an FSM.

What I have at the moment is pretty basic as I'm still quite new to programming. It'd be great if you could keep any possible solutions to around a basic level.

```
public override void Execute()
{
    //Logic for Idle state
    if (dirRight)
        oFSM.transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    else
        oFSM.transform.Translate(-Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (oFSM.transform.position.x >= 2.0f)
        dirRight = false;
    else if (oFSM.transform.position.x <= -2.0f)
        dirRight = true;
    //play animation

    //Transition out of Idle state
    //SUBJECT TO CHANGE
    float timer = 0f;
    timer += Time.time;
    if (timer >= 3f)
    {
        int rng = Random.Range(0, 5);
        if (rng >= 0 && rng <= 1)
        {
            timer = 0;
            oFSM.ChangeStateTo(FSM.States.AtkPatt1);
        }
        else if (rng >= 2 && rng <= 3)
        {
            timer = 0;
            oFSM.ChangeStateTo(FSM.States.AtkPatt2);
        }
        else if (rng >= 4 && rng <= 5)
        {
            timer = 0;
            oFSM.ChangeStateTo(FSM.States.AtkPatt3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a variable old_timer.  At the end of the function let old_timer = timer.  The the time difference is timer - old_timer

Comment: How would the code look like?

Comment: float timer = 0f;
float timer = 0f;
float old_timer = 0f;
    if (timer >= 3f)
    {
    }
float old_timer = timer;

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html), and use the method [WaitForSeconds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html).

Then you can do something like this:

```
private float timeToWait = 3f;
private bool keepExecuting = false;
private Coroutine executeCR;

public void CallerMethod()
{
    // If the Coroutine is != null, we will stop it.
    if(executeCR != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(executeCR);
    }

    // Start Coroutine execution: 
    executeCR = StartCoroutine( ExecuteCR() );
}

public void StoperMethod()
{
    keepExecuting = false;
}

private IEnumerator ExecuteCR()
{
    keepExecuting = true;

    while (keepExecuting)
    {
        // do something
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToWait);

        int rng = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 5);
        if (rng >= 0 && rng <= 1)
        {
            oFSM.ChangeStateTo(FSM.States.AtkPatt1);
        }
        else if (rng >= 2 && rng <= 3)
        {
            oFSM.ChangeStateTo(FSM.States.AtkPatt2);
        }
        else if (rng >= 4 && rng <= 5)
        {
            oFSM.ChangeStateTo(FSM.States.AtkPatt3);
        }

    }

    // All Coroutines should "return" (they use "yield") something
    yield return null;    
}
```